# Simple audio player that plays multiple audio files at the same time on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I'm creating a website that allows to play many different audios files (mp3) at the same time. All of them are looped and they have different length, so it will sound always a little bit different. That's the goal, but I can't make it happen!

This is the js code that I have at the moment and here you can find an example with different frog calls → http://petitbardo.club/

Please, help! And thanks a lot :-)

```
    function audioPlayer(){
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
           $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
        });
        
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
           currentSong++;
            if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Currently you only have 1 `<audio>` element for all of the sounds. The simple solution would be to add an `<audio>` element for each sound in your playlist. That way they can run together. Alternatively you could use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API) to play all your sounds with just JavaScript. It's a bit harder, but has more powerful features.

Comment: Also, I would recommend not using jQuery here. Does it give you any benefit over vanilla JS?